Something wrong with nuxt3 localization
When I am trying to localize a nuxt app(using typescript), I read the document and decided to use @nuxtjs/i18n. I completely follow the document to configure my project. I first run yarn add @nuxtjs/i18n. Then I changed the nuxt.config.ts
  modules: [
     '@nuxtjs/i18n'
  ],
  i18n: {
    vueI18n: './config/i18n.config.ts' // if you are using custom path, default
  },

and ~/config/i18n.config.ts
import en from '../lang/en.json'
import zh_CN from '../lang/zh-CN.json'
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'zh-CN',
    messages: {
        en,
        zh_CN
    }
}))

language files:
zh-CN.json
{
    "auth": {
        "login": "登录",
        "register": "注册",
        "submit": "提交"
    }
}

en.json
{
    "auth": {
        "login": "Login",
        "register": "Register",
        "submit": "Submit"
    }
}

When I run this program, I got this error at {{ $t('auth.login') }} in VScode: Identifier expected. And this error in the console at the same code line: Pre-transform error: unknown: Unexpected token (16:40)
If there is anything important that I don't mention, please tell me. Any help is appreciated.

It has been solved. I noticed that it don't support tsx file. After I use vue format file, it works well.
